# Offline maps in Windows for 7.5.2.1

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have Anywhere 7.5.2.1 but I can not see where to put the .tpk file in a windows environment.

The standard config guide tells me to edit this line in the app.xml for iOS and Android, but there are no instructions for Windows.

```
<map adjustToTop="true" androidLocalMapUrl="file://mnt/sdcard/basemaps/Manhattan.tpk" id="WorkExecution.MapView_esri_true" iosLocalMapUrl="Manhattan.tpk" iosMapAccessMethod="useDocumentsFolder" layoutInsertAt="map" provider="esri" workOfflineResource="workOrder"/>
```

Any help or pointers to documentation would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

We don't support maps on Windows tablet yet.  Can you open an enhancement request through the IBM rfe tool?

Comment: Just to set the record straight I seem to have two profiles here ownimage and keith.hart@vetasi.com. I have just enabled maps on the Windows 8.1 device, and I do get a map of the world shown coming from http://server.arcgisonline.com. 

Also are you saying that it is not possible to add a tpk file into the windows build.

Comment: Yes that's correct no offline esri tpk support on Windows tablet.